# Lipschitz continuity for Picard Lindelöf

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the initial value problem $
     \left\{\begin{array}{ll} u'(t)= 2 \sqrt{|u(t)|}, & \\
         u(t_0)=u_0 \in \mathbb{R}. & \end{array}\right. 
  $

Why  is $f: [0,T] \times \{v \in \mathbb{R} \mid |v-\frac{1}{4}|\leq r\}$ with $r>0$ defined by $f(t,v):=2 \sqrt{|v|}$ uniformly lipschitz continuous in v?
I want to use Picard-Lindelöf here.

Comment: You have to be precise about the domain of $f$ you have in mind. If you consider all possible $v$, $f$ is not uniformly Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @ArcticChar you're right, I edited it.

Comment: Your $f$ is not uniformly Lipchitz continuous.